# SQL. Как правильно выбирать "оба" варианта

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть таблица с пользователями. 
Каким образом я могу выбрать пользователей, которые готовы нанять преподавателя любого пола, очно или удаленно (т.е. каждый раз подходят все варианты). 
Как правильно формировать запросы, если подходят не все критерии, а N критериев?

Сейчас мой запрос выглядит так:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (goal = (?) OR goal = (?) AND gender = (?) OR gender = (?))''', goal + gender,)

goal = ('office', 'remote')
gender = ('male', 'female')
```

Comment: Думаю вам охотнее помогут, если вы сделаете картинки строения ваших таблиц. Иначе можно представить выборку, где просто селект одной строки.

Comment: Добавил, благодарю.

Comment: `where goal in ... and gender in ...`

Comment: `WHERE ? IN (users.gender, 'оба')`, и то же с местом.

Comment: Оба варианта имеют недостаток. 
where goal in: нужно менять количество '?' символов внутри скобок.
IN (users.gender, 'оба') - выберет только тех, у кого стоит "оба", тоже не годится

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (goal LIKE "%" AND gender LIKE "%")
```

Comment: А что дальше? Допустим, напишу я "any", имея ввиду любой `gender`, но это выберет только тех, у кого стоит конкретно "any"...

Comment: нет, в данном случае выберется все, что бы не выбрал пользователь